# Flutter ChangeNotifierProvider builder is deprecated

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code in my main.dart:

```
main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => Auth()), // /**problem here. builder displayed with strikethrough line**/
      ],
      child: App(),
    ),
  );
}
```

since about 2 days ago, my visual studio code showing this warning:

[image]

so I guess builder parameter on ChangeNotifierProvider is deprecated. I searched everywhere but can't find alternative to this builder parameter. So how to remove these warning? Below is my flutter version using `flutter --version` command on Windows 10

```
> flutter --version
Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 68587a0916 (3 months ago) • 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
Engine • revision b863200c37
Tools • Dart 2.5.0
```

For any help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Since provider version 3.2.0 "builder" is marked as deprecated in favor of "create".

More info can be found in the [change log](https://pub.dev/packages/provider#-changelog-tab-)

So should do:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Auth())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it saves my time.

Answer (score 12):

you can pass with create as builder.

```dart
    return Provider<MyProvider>(
        create: (context) => MyProvider(

        ),
        child: HomePage(),
    );
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but I choose @Nuts' answer because his description is clearer

Answer (score 6):

you can use "create" instead of "builder"

```
main() {
 runApp(
   MultiProvider(
     providers: [
       ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => Auth()), // /**problem here. 
builder displayed with strikethrough line**/
     ],
     child: App(),
   ),
 );
```

}

Comment: please delete your answer, because your answer not adding anything to existing answers. @Tabrizapps

Answer (score 2):

Instead of builder parameter you can use create param with **Product()** or specific product at Index.

```
itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => products[i],
        child:  ProductItem(),
      ),
```

Or can be use as Value version:

```
itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
        value: products[i],
        child:  ProductItem(),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to **use** `create` instead of `build` because of *deprecation*.

*Wrong code example:*

[image]

***True code example:***

[image]