# How to use Multiple Providers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use Multiple providers in my application, but i'm facing some compile time error at builder by using below code

**Code**

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => FirstProvider()),
ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => SecondProvider()),
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use MultiProvider to do so. as following.

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => FirstProvider()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => SecondProvider()),
  ],
  child: someWidget,
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey **builder** was deprecated you can refer this link for more info [Builder Deprecation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100723/flutter-changenotifierprovider-builder-is-deprecated)

We can use Multiple providers like this

```
 MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider<ProductDataProvider>(
                create: (_) => ProductDataProvider()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthenticationProvider>(
                create: (_) => AuthenticationProvider()),
          ],
          child: Container())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this:

```dart
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => CartModel()),
        Provider(create: (context) => SomeOtherClass()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
```

Comment: Smart answer for considering, that Providers could be used without ChangNotifiers too! +1. thanks!