# StreamProvider is not responding to changed value of stream

Tags: flutter

I am making a flutter application where i need to register into firebase.
First I have **SignInPage()** which uses Navigator to redirect to **ResidentRegister()**.Here is the form for registering into the application. The problem is the ResidentRegister() page is not getting redirected to **HomeScreen()** upon successful Authentication of the user. The user is properly registered into the firebase and **HomeScreen()** appears after hotrestart of the application. I have used StreamProvider for the purpose which should listen to a stream of type 'Resident' which is my User data model based on whether it is null or not in the **Wrapper()** class. In the 'Wrapper' class, the stream is getting 'instance of resident'(when I print the value of resident variable), but the else block is not getting executed. This is probably happening due to usage of Navigator as when I remove the first screen that is **SignInPage()**, the **ResidentRegister()** screen is successfully getting redirected to **HomeScreen()**. I don't know why this happens as I have wrapped the MaterialApp to StreamProvider widget.
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks!

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<Resident>(
      create: (_)=> AuthService().resident,
      child: Consumer<Resident>(
        builder: (context, resident, _)
        {
          return MaterialApp(
              home: (user != null) ? HomeScreen() : SignInPage(),
          );
        },

      ),
    );
  }
}



class SignInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  SignInPage({this.title});
  final String title;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('JNMCH eLogBook'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Sign In',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.teal,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                fontSize: 65,
              ),),
            SizedBox(height: 35,),
            
            CustomButton(text: 'Sign In as a Resident', onPressed: ()=> Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/residentRegister')),
            SizedBox(height:8.0),
            CustomButton(text: 'Sign In as a Mentor', onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/mentorSignIn')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class ResidentRegister extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ResidentRegisterState createState() => _ResidentRegisterState();
}

class _ResidentRegisterState extends State<ResidentRegister> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email;
  String _password;
  String _confirmPassword;
  String _error = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Register as a Resident'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 80.0, horizontal: 40.0),
                child: Card(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  elevation: 8.0,
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
                        Text('Register',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.teal,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                            fontSize: 65,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 35,),
                        TextFormField(
                          validator: (val) => val.isEmpty ? 'Enter an email' : null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Email'
                          ),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _email = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
                        TextFormField(
                          validator: (val) => val.length < 6 ? 'Enter a password 6+ char long' : null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Password'
                          ),
                          obscureText: true,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _password = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
                        TextFormField(
                          validator: (val) => val!=_password ? 'Confirm Password must be same as password' : null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Confirm Password'
                          ),
                          obscureText: true,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _confirmPassword = value;
                            });

                          },
                         ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          child: ButtonTheme(
                            minWidth: 150,
                            height: 50,
                            child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () async {
                              if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                                dynamic result = await _auth.register( _email,_password);
                                if(result == null){
                                  setState(() {
                                    _error = 'Please supply a valid email';
                                  });
                                }
                              

                              }
                            },
                              color: Colors.teal,
                              child:
                              Text(
                                'Submit',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20,),
                              ),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0),
                                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.teal[100]),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
                        Text(_error, style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),),
                        SizedBox(height: 20,),
                        FlatButton(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          textColor: Colors.grey[600],
                          disabledColor: Colors.black,
                          disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          splashColor: Colors.teal,
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "Already have an account? Sign In!",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home Page'),
        actions: <Widget> [
          FlatButton.icon(

              onPressed: ()async {
                await _auth.signOut();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.white,),
              label: Text('Sign Out', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class AuthService{
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create resident user object based on Firebase User
  Resident _residentFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user){
      return user!=null ? Resident(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  //auth change user stream
   Stream<Resident> get resident {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
        .map(_residentFromFirebaseUser);

   }

   //register with email and password
   Future register(String email, String password) async{
    try{
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      print(user);
      return _residentFromFirebaseUser(user);
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  //sign out
Future signOut() async{
    try{
      return await _auth.signOut();
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
}

}

class Resident{
  final String uid;
  Resident({ this.uid });

}
```

Comment: try to remove final from `final resident = Provider.of<Resident>(context);` or uncomment this line `//updateShouldNotify: (_, __) => true,`

Comment: Thanks for the help but both didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using `StreamProvider` incorrectly. It shouldn't be:

```
StreamProvider<Resident>.value(value: ...)
```

Instead, try using:

```
StreamProvider<Resident>(
  create: (_) => AuthService().resident,
  child: Consumer<Resident>(
    builder: (context, resident, _) {
      // TODO: return home page or sign in page based on data
    },
  ),
);
```

That should **subscribe** to the stream and rebuild on new events.

Comment: I changed the code to: StreamProvider<Resident>(
      create: (context)=> AuthService().resident, still not working

Comment: Are you definitely using this correctly with the builder argument?

    return StreamProvider<Resident>(
      create: (_) => AuthService().resident,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // return home page or sign in page based on snapshot  
      },
    );

Comment: I tried to use the builder parameter but compiler says it is deprecated with a strikethrough on the word 'builder' like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59100723/flutter-changenotifierprovider-builder-is-deprecated

Comment: Still not working :( Edited the code above which I tried