# Using builder and create both in Flutter's ChangeNotifierProvider

Tags: flutter, dart

This is from: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-get-to-know-flutter#1

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ApplicationState(),
      builder: (context, _) => App(),
    ),
  );
}
```

That's flutter's website so I thought code is trustworthy which means perhaps `create` and `builder` both are required.

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59101137/462608.
says that `builder` is depreciated and `create` should be used instead.

But the above code is using *create* and *builder* both.
**What is the use of this *builder* here when *create* is also there? How are *builder* and *create* different from each other?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, there big difference between  create and builder

- create : if you want to instantiate you notifier you should use create
  but if you notifier already instantiate you don't need use create
  simply use ChangeNotifierProvider.value
- builder : usefull if you have some condition to show specific widget
  for example if in your logic you need tp  choose between 2 widget to be showen
  you will use builder and you passe it child it's the static widget

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ApplicationState(),
      builder: (context, child){
           if(condition){
             return SomeWidget();
           }
          return child;
      },
     child:App(),
    )
```

except that no need for builder

Comment: Please talk about buider being depreciated and people saying use create instead.

Comment: it's deprecated because the most of cases no need for it
and you can directly use create and child parameter