# Flutter How to get the context of the provider across classes

Tags: flutter, state, provider, consumer

EDIT: Im retarded, i figured it out

1. used the widget. to get access to the class variable
2. swapped out the Text("fsfd); for my list variable resulting in

   ```
     child: Consumer<WidgetDataNotify>(
                                    builder: (context,datatonotify,child){
                                      print("value == ${datatonotify.value}");
                                      return FuctionListSet[datatonotify.value];
                                    },
                                    child: Text("${provtest.value}"),
   ```

i've been following
[Flutter provider state not updating in consumer widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58317152/flutter-provider-state-not-updating-in-consumer-widget)
to try and understand the process along with the documentation and videos ect ect.
and i cannot figure out how to ensure im using the same instance of a provider across classes (dart files)

My program is composed of widgets and a radiolist that when it's clicked will update the provider to it's index value which then from a list in my main (thats wrapped) in a consumer will update depending on the interger affecting the list

provider file:

```
class WidgetDataNotify extends ChangeNotifier {

  int value=0;
  //int get grabvalue => value;

  // Widget SelectedWidget=SingleButtonMovementFunction();
  // Widget get pickedWidget =>SelectedWidget=FuctionListSet[value];

  void UpdateWidgetList(int picker){
    value = picker;
    print("updated value to $value");
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

RadioList code: Problem here is i dont know how to communicate that provider value i've passed in

```
class RadioListBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final int num;
  static int value=0;
  final WidgetDataNotify provider;

  const RadioListBuilder({Key key, this.num,this.provider}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  RadioListBuilderState createState() {
    return RadioListBuilderState();
  }
}

class RadioListBuilderState extends State<RadioListBuilder> {
  static int test;
  int _value;
  


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            Container(
            height: 60,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.brown[800],
            child: RadioListTile(
              selectedTileColor: Colors.amber,
              activeColor: Colors.amber,
              tileColor: Colors.black54,
              value: index,
              groupValue: _value,
              onChanged: (x) => setState((){
                _value = x;

                ///provider.UpdateWidgetList(x);   /// providing the value to the provider
                ///ideally would call the function

                Activated_Function_Selected=index;
                print("Activated fuction is indexed at $Activated_Function_Selected and it's name is == ${FunctionList[index].characters}");
              }),
              title: Text("${FunctionList[index]}",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 18,),softWrap: true,maxLines: 2,),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(color: Colors.black,height: 10,thickness: 10,),
        ],
        );
      },
      itemCount: widget.num,
    );
  }
}
```

Start of my main function has this to ensure the context would be the same

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetDataNotify provtest = Provider.of<WidgetDataNotify>(context,listen: true);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
```

i pass this on into my radio list

```
                          Expanded(
                              flex:2 ,
                              child: Container(
                                color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                child: RadioListBuilder(num: FunctionList.length,provider: provtest,),
                                  ),
                                ),
```

then i have my consumer listen out for it

```
                            Expanded(
                                flex: 3,
                                child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,

                                  //
                                  // child: Selector<WidgetDataNotify, int>(
                                  //   selector: (context,model) => model.value,
                                  //   builder: (context,value,child){
                                  //     print("accesed value==$value");
                                  //     return Center(
                                  //       child: FuctionListSet[value],
                                  //     );
                                  //   },
                                  //   child: Text("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"),
                                  // ),

                                  child: Consumer<WidgetDataNotify>(
                                    builder: (context,datatonotify,child){
                                      print("value == ${datatonotify.value}");
                                      testA=datatonotify.value;
                                      print("test == $testA");
                                      return Text("faf");
                                    },
                                    child: Text("${provtest.value}"),

                                  ),


                                ),
                                  //),),

                          ),
```

Comment: oh i remembered i should use 
widget.provider.UpdateWidgetList(x);
any other tips would be welcomed !!!!

Comment: Its best to use another state management solution like Bloc or Streams/Rxdart to update your widgets. All of your Consumer widgets would rebuild when calling `notifyListeners`. You could try using Selector but its still not as good as bloc

Comment: Ah yeah i did quickly swap to selector once i got it working.
Since that consumer is at the end of my tree wouldnt that be fine ?

Comment: Consumer and Selector is pretty much the same with a subtle difference. Selector will only rebuild if the data you need changes. Its still better to use bloc